# PHP based image management

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, image-processing, code-reuse

A reason I've picked up working with the Zend Framework was that I keep hearing how easy it is to reuse code and not have to reinvent the wheel every time you start a new project. 
I do find this true for my own code, but find it pretty hard to find quality external sources that can integrate well into the system.

Anyway, I'm basically looking for pre written PHP code (preferably supported by frontend js scripts) that s flexible and wraps the most common tasks relating to image management. (cropping scaling, validation of mimetypes/sizes/dimensions etc) into a useful/flexible class.

Any recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Anyway, I'm basically looking for pre written PHP code (preferably supported by frontend js scripts) that s flexible and wraps the most common tasks relating to image management.

I'm not sure you're going to find a *complete* general-purpose drop-it-in component for this, but you can stitch something together without a problem.

[jcrop](http://code.google.com/p/jcrop/) is a jQuery plugin to handle the client-side bits of image cropping.

[Imagine](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine) is a new PHP image handler, wrapping either GD or the Imagick/Gmagick extensions.  It has a powerful, convenient, fluent interface with [comprehensive cropping, thumbnailing and resizing support](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine/blob/master/docs/en/image.rst).

As for gluing them together, that'll be up to you... but given that these two libraries can handle most of the work, it should just be some quick bits and pieces in your controller code.

Comment: Sorry, didn't expect it to be drop in, I can integrate it, just didn't want to have to put together 4 libraries for 4 related functions

Comment: +1 for the Imagine reference. Beat me to it. ;-) Worth noting that Imagine requires PHP 5.3

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check [Nette Image](http://doc.nette.org/en/images). It has far the best interface I've seen ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's true that code reuse isn't very complicated, but making pieces of code from all over the place work TOGETHER can be very complicated. Have you looked into using a more general purpose framework like CakePHP?

Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648/what-php-framework-would-you-choose-for-a-new-application-and-why